# Reconnecting to GKMatch with more than two players

Tags: ios5, game-center, gamekit, reconnect

I'm testing a Game Center Game and specifically what happens when a player drops out temporarily (phone call, background etc) I want to be able to pause the game and reconnect when the player comes alive again.

This works fine in a two player game because of the match:shouldReinvitePlayer functionality which causes the player to be re-invited but this is specified by Apple only to work in a two player game.

In a three player (or more) game I am handling this in the appDelegate applicationWillEnterForeground as follows;

```
GKMatchRequest *comebackRequest = [[GKMatchRequest alloc] init];
    comebackRequest.playersToInvite = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[[[[KYTGame instance] players] objectAtIndex:1] peerId], [[[[KYTGame instance] players] objectAtIndex:2] peerId], nil];
    comebackRequest.minPlayers = 3;
    comebackRequest.maxPlayers = 3;
    comebackRequest.playerGroup = [[[KYTGame instance] gameCategory] playerGroup];

    [[GKMatchmaker sharedMatchmaker] addPlayersToMatch:[[KYTGame instance] match] 
                                          matchRequest:comebackRequest 
                                     completionHandler:^(NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"%sPlayers are %@", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, [[KYTGame instance] match ].playerIDs);
    }];
```

What happens is that the existing two players 'ping' away happily, when the app delegate code gets called (in the player that is coming alive again) the match is not nil and there is nothing in the playedIDs array but the completion handler never seems to get called and the player that is 'coming alive' again never gets reconnected.

I also get a peculiar pattern in the debug log of the 'live' players showing me that the player that has gone into the background has changed status to 'disconnected' more than once without any 'connected' in between.

So ... is it okay to expect a GKMATCH to make sense when it has been pushed into the background and then resurrected.  How can I reconnect? Is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

I submitted this to Apple support and unfortunately the functionality is not available; although Game Kit supports up to 4 players in a peer to peer network, if there are more than 2
players in the game then the api does not provide a way to reconnect in the event that any of them gets disconnected.

Comment: Has this changed since September of 2012?  Seems like a feature that other apps (mine in particular)  could really use.